# React Native Top Tab Navigation screens not showing

Tags: react-native

I have a top tab navigation as shown here

```
 <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                    <Tab.Navigator
                        initialRouteName="Profile"
                        initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height }}
                        screenOptions={({ route })  => ({
                            tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.colors.primary,
                            tabBarStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                elevation: 0,
                            },
                            tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                height: 0,
                            },
                            tabBarAndroidRipple: {
                                color: 'transparent'
                            },
                            tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.colors.gray[700],
                            tabBarLabel: ({ focused, color, position }) => {
                                return (
                                    <Text
                                        style={{
                                            color: focused ? theme.colors.primary : theme.colors.gray[700],
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: focused ? '700' : '400',
                                            textTransform: 'none',
                                            fontFamily: 'Poppins_400Regular',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {route.name}
                                    </Text>
                                );
                            },
                            swipeEnabled: true,
                        })}
                        style={{
                            minHeight: height * 0.75,
                            justifyContent: 'center'
                        }}
                    >
                        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileGeneral}/>
                        <Tab.Screen name="Gallery" component={ProfileGallery}/>
                        <Tab.Screen name="Interests" component={ProfileInterests}/>
                    </Tab.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
```

If I remove this line

```
style={{
          minHeight: height * 0.75,
         justifyContent: 'center'
      }}
```

The screens wont show up. First image is with the min height set, and the second one is without the style attribute

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated